# Modify item while iterating

Tags: python, list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in a:
   a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

results : [2, 4]

I read a post about modifying list while iterating, and then I tried the code above, the result seems a little confusing.
Why the results here is [2, 4]?

Comment: Have you tried to step through with a debugger? Or write out what is happening.

Comment: This _should_ be _more than_ confusing.  It's a good thing.  Stay away from modifying the collection while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the collection you are iterating on. This will do the trick:

> for element in lst[:] :
>          lst.remove(element)